# What is wrong with ZFC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, foundations, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

Why are there seemingly so many who want to use ETCS, or HoTT, or similar as a foundation of mathematics? I'm aware that HoTT has a good few good aspects, but that doesn't entirely explain the strong desire to find *something* other than ZFC to use, so I ask:

What is actually wrong with ZFC that drives this desire?

I've heard a few arguments already, though they were a bit vague - I'll list them below.

1. As all the objects of ZFC are sets, in ZFC questions such as "is $\pi \in 3$" may be asked, and for some reason just the fact that that may be asked is a problem...but I can't really see the issue. You never need to ask those questions so where would they cause a problem?
2. Another argument is that ZFC has too much "baggage" caused by the cumulative hierarchy - we don't want to have to worry about the set theoretical aspects of the elements of the real numbers, for example. This, again, is lost on me - can anyone give an example of where we ever actually feel the need to say anything at all about such aspects? Surely once you've got your definitions and you have a few properties that you want you can proceed to deduce using only those properties and may safely ignore those you don't want to think about?

You'll never get a false theorem from ignoring an axiom - when one proves something about groups in general it does not matter what extraneous properties individual groups have, they follow the group axioms so the conclusion is valid. Similarly we know what properties we want the real numbers to have, so surely we can deduce from those without any real issue once we have an object with those (though possibly other) properties?

3. The last apparent issue I'll mention is categories. Apparently ZFC (let's assume with Universes) is a headache for category theorists. Something about ZFC makes category theory harder than it would be in, say, homotopy type theoretic foundations. So far all I've seen is hand waving - can anyone give an example of where ZFC(+U) truly makes life so much more difficult for category theorists? What is the problem?

I know that this is a negative post, asking what is *wrong* with ZFC rather than what is *right* about HoTT, ETCS, etc, it's just that I've seen many vague references from those disgruntled with the set theory, but not yet any concrete grievances.

As with many of my unusual questions, the tags are guesswork.

Comment: 1. I think some researchers are looking for alternatives just to see if there are some. 2. Set-theoretical aspects  come up in many questions in analysis and topology,e.g. (a) Is every strongly-Lebesgue-null  subset of R a countable set? (b)Can Lebesgue measure be extended to a countably additive measure whose domain is all subsets of R? (c)Does every non-measurable subset of R have the same cardinal as R? (d) Does there exist a  linear topological space whose density exceeds its cellularity?

Comment: One might complain that questions like "Is $3 \subseteq \pi$?" are problematic because some ZFCers will answer yes (e.g. fans of Dedekind cuts) while other ZFCers will answer no (e.g. fans of Cauchy sequences.) But I agree that it's no big deal. As you observed, nobody's interested in theorems about Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences. People are interested in theorems about complete ordered fields.

Comment: @user254665 How does leaving set theory give answers to these set theoretical aspects?

Comment: I sort of feel [that I kinda answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406462/motivation-for-different-mathematics-foundations) that already.

Comment: From what I understand, the fact that statements such as $\pi \in 3$ even make sense is seen as a huge problem. People agree that you never want to ask questions like this, but they then argue that the fact that you can points to a weakness in the foundations, a sort of a lack of structure.

Comment: @Miha: Those people don't understand the point of a foundational theory, then. I wonder how they feel when they think about how all the data types in their code, all the different objects... are just bitfields in the RAM/pagefile. Do they plan on shunning away computers too for this reason? :-) Or the fact that you can inject asm snippets to directly manipulate whatever data type you want as bitfields... Those damn bitfields!

Comment: I am a category theorist.  I sort of agree with you; there is nothing wrong with ZFC as a foundations.  It shows that a great many things mathematicians do are consistent.  My big complaint is that it is used in teaching to define many mathematical structures (a real number is a Dedekind cut, a pair (a,b) is {a,{a,b}}) in a way that makes them seem bizarre and unintuitive.  That works in showing consistency.  Such things should never be exposed to students beginning a subject since it makes the learn a difficult idea that will do them no good whatever.

Comment: @SixWingedSeraph: I don't even recall it was *set theory* that was used to show that real numbers are Dedekind cuts, or equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, both the constructions came before set theory existed. I do recall that it was part of the need to show why *there is* such an object to begin with. ZFC has ***absolutely nothing*** to do with your complaint. You're pointing it at the wrong issue here. Not to mention, that unlike ETCS, ZFC is interpretation agnostic. So once you've shown there is a model for the real numbers, nobody cares which sets you've used anymore.

Comment: @Nethesis: Did the answer on the linked question help you at all? Did it *not* answer all your questions? Did it answer some of them? Do you want me to expand on some of the points? Did you kill JFK? Was it you who leaked Watergate to the press? Any reaction at all?

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" ... What is wrong with Newtonian mechanics ? we landed on the Moon with it (and much more) ! But, in spite of this, Einstein found a "better" theory (relativity) improving our knowledge of physical world.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Just digesting the various responses. Your answer did help, and you were impartial about it but, personally, I'd prefer to hear directly from someone who is actually advocating for a different foundation

Comment: @AsafKaragila *before just leaving this

Comment: @AsafKaragila what do you think is more "interpretation agnostic" about ZFC than about ETCS?  In either theory one can build the real numbers and then ignore how it was done.

Comment: @Mike: That really came up in Thomas Forester's answer to David Roberts' question about replacement. Replacement is equivalent to saying that any two ways to interpret ordered pairs are isomorphic. This idea easily extends to things like the real numbers. And ETCS is without replacement. So it can't possibly be interpretation agnostic in the same way as ZFC.

Comment: @AsafKaragila maybe not in the same *way* as ZFC, but probably that "way of being interpretation agnostic" wouldn't even make sense for ETCS.  It _is_ interpretation agnostic in the appropriate way for itself, e.g. any cartesian product is isomorphic to any other.

Comment: @Mike: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't ETCS bi-interpretable with Z? And since we can provably pull these shenanigans there, doesn't it mean we can translate them back to ETCS?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes, but it would be stupid and miss the point.  If you translate Z-shenanigans about ordered pairs into ETCS, what you'll get is that there may be more than one way to "interpret ordered pairs" within the model of Z that you can construct in ETCS.  But that sort of "interpret ordered pairs" is not a sensical way to actually interpret "ordered pair" when doing mathematics in ETCS; we don't do math in ETCS by first doing it in Z and then translating, we use ETCS directly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila By the way, can you please post a link to "Thomas Forester's answer to David Roberts' question about replacement" so I can see what you're specifically talking about?

Comment: @Mike: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208711/who-needs-replacement-anyway in any case "that's not a sensical way to ..." is not a real argument. Since as you may as well know, you can have a theory which is fool proof, but not ingenious-fool proof. :-)

Comment: From the perspective of ETCS, that argument takes a useless definition of "ordered pair" and then says that replacement is equivalent to "any notion of ordered pair admits cartesian products".  The problem is not that some ingenious fool might come along and invent a definition of ordered pair that doesn't have cartesian products; the problem is that _you've_ left the door open for the ingenious fool by formulating the definition in the wrong way.  The correct definition of "ordered pair" should _include_ the existence of cartesian products.

Comment: @Mike: I disagree with that last assessment, but this is a philosophical difference, and I guess we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: It's not a philosophical difference between two people as much as it is between two theories.  In ZFC it makes sense for an "ordered pair" to be simply something whose equality is detected by equality of its components (or whatever your definition is); but in ETCS it does not, because there is no relevant "global equality" to even phrase such a definition with.  You can only phrase it inside a model of Z that you build inside ETCS, and the result is not a "native" definition to ETCS, only something that you've coded inside of it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As many of the commenters have said, nothing is "wrong" with ZFC at a practical level; it's just that other theories have certain advantages.  I'm not sure what you're referring to by "the strong desire to find *something* other than ZFC to use" — for the most part I've only seen people pointing out advantages of particular other theories rather than complaining that ZFC is broken on its own.

The first two disadvantages you point out are, as you say, not of *practical* importance for using ZFC as a foundation for mathematics.  But they are not worthless observations either.  If nothing else, they are important *philosophical* observations that there are ways in which ZFC doesn't match the everyday practice of mathematicians, so it ought to be of philosophical interest that there are other foundations that do match it better.

There is also a *pedagogical* point to make: the working mathematician may have no trouble ignoring an axiom, but a student just learning mathematics may get the wrong impression about how sets are actually used in mathematics from a ZFC-oriented introduction.  (Indeed, pedagogical considerations were what first let Lawvere to invent ETCS.)

And there is also a question of *extensibility*: as we try to interpret a foundational theory in "nonstandard" models (I put the word in quotes because it has an undesired negative connotation), it is significantly easier if we use a foundational theory that looks more like the models that we are interested in as they arise naturally — namely, as categories, not as cumulative hierarchies.  One can, with some effort, build a cumulative hierarchy from a category, but it doesn't always capture exactly what one wants, and why force oneself to go through the pain when there are other perfectly good foundational theories that we could use instead of ZFC?

As for category theory, there are at least two reasons a category theorist might be dissatisfied with set theory.  One is the awkward treatment of universes used to deal with "large categories", but the alternative foundations that you mentioned (ETCS, HoTT) don't really do anything to solve that problem.  (There are other alternative foundations, such as those proposed by Feferman, which do attempt to address that question, but I don't know as much about them.)

Another issue with set theory for category theory is that any two objects in set theory can be equal, whereas in category theory we generally only want to consider objects up to isomorphism, or categories up to equivalence, and so on into higher dimensions.  You might think this is just like the question of nonsense statements $3\in \pi$, since you can just ignore the notion of equality and use isomorphism.  However, technically you then incur an obligation to *prove* that all theorems and constructions respect isomorphism (or equivalence).  Nobody actually does this in everyday mathematics, it being regarded as obvious; but when you start formalizing mathematics in a computer, it becomes necessary and tedious.  ETCS and HoTT do have some advantages here: in ETCS formulated appropriately, one can prove a metatheorem that *everything* transports across isomorphism; whereas in HoTT this transportability is part of the basic theory (the univalence axiom).

To be fair, I should note that ZFC itself has some advantages over other foundational theories.  In particular, it is very well-adapted for what the mathematicians who call themselves "set theorists" use it for, namely the study of well-founded relations.  Most of the results of modern set theory could be formulated and proven in alternative foundations, but they often become significantly more awkward.

Comment: I should add to your final remark that set theorists study structure of models of set theory, but *a lot* of it reflects back down to the real numbers and their subsets. So these results are ultimately not isolated from the rest of mathematics.

Comment: Thank you, that certainly clears up most of my confusion over this. Out of interest, has any work been done on the ability of isomorphisms to transfer theorems (couldn't think up a better term) between sets of ZFC? It can't quite work the same as equality, of course,  but there must be some translation that occurs? Maybe for objects $A$, $B$, with $f: A\to B$ an isomorphism allows $\Phi (x) \Leftrightarrow \Phi (f(x))$ for $x\in A$ and logical formulae $\Phi$? I highly doubt it would be anywhere near that simple, I'm almost certain that it isn't as universal, but has anything been shown?

Comment: @Nethesis: It is in fact almost trivial just by the definition of Tarskian truth (induction, induction, induction). Even in $\sf ZFC$. It's true that usually we don't check that and we don't care about that very much.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you direct me to some source for this so I know exactly how it is stated? Or a least a pointer about what to search for? I'm curious about this

Comment: @Nethesis: No idea. One of these things you learn on the job, I guess.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But it can't be as simple as I've stated, even just the statement $x\in A\cup\{A\}$ wouldn't translate exactly. Sure, the reality is that you get $f(x)\in f(A) \cup \{f(A)\}$, which is basically there. Is there a general rule which has been proven to be universally applicable?

Comment: @Nethesis: Because you're thinking about it wrong. It's not the isomorphism of $\in$, as much as it is an isomorphism of *first-order structures*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh of course, how silly of me

Comment: What you get from univalence is $\Phi(x) \iff \Phi(f(x))$ for any $\Phi$ at all, not just the $\Phi$s belonging to some first-order theory of which $A$ and $B$ are structures.  For instance, $\Phi(G)=$ "$G$ is an initial object in the category of groups", which is not a statement in the first-order language of groups.

Comment: I am still not entirely sure why this is not a metatheorem with a reasonable formulation in a ZFC foundation. But I will take your word that it is easier to formulate it with HoTT.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Because of examples like Nethesis's.  $\Phi(x):=(\emptyset \in x)$ doesn't translate across an isomorphism $x\cong y$.

Comment: Okay, either I *completely* don't understand what you mean by univalence or isomorphism here, or something else maybe. So can you please point me to the nearest definition of what you meant *exactly* by $\Phi(x)\iff\Phi(f(x))$ for "any $\Phi$"?

Comment: In type theory a predicate is a function into the type of propositions.  So if $A:Group$ and $B:Group$ and $f:A\cong B$ is an isomorphism of groups, and $x:A$, then $f$ is also an isomorphism $(A,x) \cong (B,f(x))$ of pointed groups, and hence by univalence an equality $(A,x)=(B,f(x))$ in the type $PGroup$ of pointed groups.  Thus, for any function $\Phi:PGroup \to Prop$, we have $\Phi(A,x) = \Phi(B,f(x))$.

Comment: Okay, but that's not what you're doing. You're trying to do type theory in a purely set theoretical setting. You can argue, again, that I left the door open for this which is why this argument can be made at all, but then I can tell you that you're missing the point, and we'll end up with another philosophical disagreement. So, since I think we're both familiar with these things to a sufficient level, we can leave it at that. At least until we have the option to continue this over beer.

Comment: What made you think I was trying to do type theory in a purely set theoretical setting?  (And what do you even mean by that?)  I'm just talking about type theory on its own.

Comment: @MikeShulman It has been a while, but I'm not too sure how to contact you. What has happened to SEAR? Has it been entirely subsumed by homotopy type theory? It seems like some of the pedagogical aspects of SEAR were quite nice, and so far as I can tell have been lost in the move to HoTT.

Comment: @Nethesis No, SEAR is not subsumed by HoTT, any more than ETCS or ZFC is; they are different systems.  I have been spending more of my time on HoTT recently, but of course SEAR still exists.